# Django. How to debug a deployed website without turning on Debug setting

Tags: django, debugging

I have a little forum that is already deployed and working. I just found out something is wrong with the Twitter login and I need to debug it. Right now it returns a 500 page. I can't know what is wrong with Debug = True. But if I turn it on, then I'll be violating Django security best practices, and if someone saves the info in the debug page (with Debug=False) and has bad intentions, he could cause lots of trouble. What would you recommend?

Comment: Try to log properly instead. ``DEBUG=True`` does not replace logging ! Check https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/logging/. Also, you can use the ``AdminEmailHandler`` to get the exception to your email.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Make sure you have access to the application logs and have properly configured the [AdminEmailHandler](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/logging/#django.utils.log.AdminEmailHandler).
2. Make sure you've property configured [`ALLOWED_HOSTS`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#allowed-hosts). If you haven't configured it and set `DEBUG=False` you'll see a [SuspiciousOperation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/exceptions/#django.core.exceptions.SuspiciousOperation) raised.
3. Double check that you have the incidentals covered. Bad database connection details will quickly cause 500 errors.
4. Have you tried running it locally with `DEBUG=False`? That's often a quick way to find out about some more esoteric errors.

---

To follow up based on the comments you'll need to turn `DEBUG` on in a somewhat live environment. The standard way to do this would be to have a separate staging environment from the live one. Since Heroku is being used you can easily spin up a separate environment and set `DEBUG=True`  there. Then you'll see the full error pages, fix the error, and deploy to production where `DEBUG=False`.

---

Another idea is to setup a third-party exception handling system like Raygun or [Bugsnag](https://bugsnag.com). Adding this to the production application will give you reports when exceptions are thrown. This is a big upgrade over Django's default email-on-error behavior.

Comment: Hi Josh thanks. After reading the documentation, I honestly don't understand how to configure logging.. where should I ´import logging´? should I do that in every view? I use Django 1.6. I would like to send the 500 error details to my email, I was hopping to find some settings config to make that possible. Maybe I'm missing something simple... Also, I use Heroku and ´ALLOWED_HOSTS=['*']´. Is it possible that Heroku's logging system could catch the error traceback?

Comment: I can't find the error locally cause it occurs during the login process, and "login with Twitter, Facebook, Google" require the redirect URI, and 'localhost' is not allowed in most cases. Thanks for your suggestions. I guess my problem now is that I don't know where the error is happening (the python social auth pipeline includes many different functions), so, I can't `import logging` and check for errors to do `logger.error()` everywhere, I bet there is a better way and I'm not understanding something.

Comment: @alejoss You'll need to turn on `DEBUG` in the live environment then. I'll update my answer.